# Перевод в табличный вид

Tags: javascript, php, css, jquery

Вопрос к знатокам `css`..или людям, чьи знания намного выше моих :)

Однажды нашел на codepen пример "таблицы", которая мне зашла..немного перегнав ее под себя встала нужда сделать из нее таблицу через `table thead` и т.п

Собственно сама таблица на codepen - https://codepen.io/ajlohman/pen/tLvdF (для понимания о чем речь)

Подскажите, как переделать данный вид "таблицы" из того, чем она является сейчас, в `table` вид

CSS предпочтительно взять этот , а структуру таблицы - без разницы :)

```
.nfl a, .mlb a, .nhl a, .pga a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}

.nfl a {
  color: #4fc0d2;
}

.nfl a:hover {
  color: #268695;
}

.mlb a {
  color: #52d29a;
}

.mlb a:hover {
  color: #279766;
}

.nhl a {
  color: rgba(231, 196, 104, 0.7);
}

.nhl a:hover {
  color: rgba(201, 154, 32, 0.7);
}

.pga a {
  color: #e74c3c;
}

.pga a:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
}

/* wrapper */
.wrapper-table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto 100px auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/* lists */
.rowg ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rowg ul li {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  .rowg ul li {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .rowg ul li {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}

.title ul li {
  padding: 15px 13px;
}

.rowg ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

/* rowgs */
.rowg {
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: white;
    color: black;

}
a.go-arb{
    padding: 10px;
    background: #e74c3c;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a.go-trade{
    padding: 10px;
    background: #27ae60;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.no-change{
    color: white;
}

.rowg:hover {
  background-color: #303030;
  height: 110px;
  color: white;
}
a.go-arb:hover {
  background-color: #ca4a3d;
  color: white;
}
a.go-trade:hover {
  background-color: #1f9250;
  color: white;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .rowg:hover {
    height: 125px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 359px) {
  .rowg:hover {
    height: 105px;
  }
}

.title {
  padding: 25px 0 5px 0;
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-left: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
}



.title:hover {
  height: 75px;
  /* background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); */
  border-left: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .title-hide {
    display: none;
  }
  .notif
  {
      padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
}

.nfl {
  border-left: 3px solid #1c616c;
}

.nfl:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #4fc0d2;
}

.mlb {
  border-left: 3px solid #1d6e4b;
}

.mlb:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #52d29a;
}

.nhl {
  border-left: 3px solid rgba(157, 121, 25, 0.7);
}

.nhl:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid rgba(231, 196, 104, 0.7);
}

.pga {
  border-left: 3px solid #e74c3c;
}

.pga:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #eb7655;
}



/* more content */
ul.more-content li {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 13px;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.9);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  ul.more-content li {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}

/* small content */
.small {
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.9);
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .small {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

А вот то, чего удалось достичь моими кривыми руками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С меня огромное спасибо и копеечка на чай (если тут можно поощрять исполнителей)

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Вам `border` нужно добавить что ли?

Comment: @ArchDemon нет нет, мне нужно сделать таблицу в этом же стиле, но не через `article, div, ul, li` разметку, а через `table, thead, tr,th,td,tbody` и т.д. Либо как то к этой адекватно присобачить сортировку..

Comment: Ну меняйте. Сложности то с чем?

Comment: @ArchDemon с тем, что не выходит корректно изменить. Написал же все прямым языком. Помощь прошу не безвозмездную. Одарю деревянным на чай.

Comment: Что именно не выходит конкретно изменить? Вы не знаете в какой последовательности должны идти table thead tr th td tbody? Вы не знаете как сделать цвет ячейке? Вы не знаете как изменить цвет текста? Уточните вопрос.

Comment: @ArchDemon Конкретно это все знаю..проблема возникает в том, что когда делаешь все под table - стили встают некорректно. Стили, соответственно, тоже переделывал под table. К тому же не получается скрыть надпись, которая появляется, когда `height` изменяется в момент `hover`. Да и работает в целом странно. Поэтому и сообщил о своих кривых руках и готов дать денежкой за работу

Comment: Приведите код с уже табличной вёрсткой и стилями для таблице. Напишите какое поведение вас не устраивает. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив туда фрагмент кода